# Declaring a variable without var in function

Tags: javascript

I tried to the opposite of what the exercise wanted. Instead of declaring a variable with var inside the function, I did it like this:

```
function myLocalScope() {
  'use strict';

  // Only change code below this line
  myVar = "bebe"
  console.log('inside myLocalScope', myVar);
}
myLocalScope();

// Run and check the console
// myVar is not defined outside of myLocalScope
console.log('outside myLocalScope', myVar);
```

I thought that since I used no var it would be global now. But it just says its not defined.
Not even in the local scope. If I add var inside the function, then the function works.

Comment: tag your question with language you used

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "use strict" do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: Variable wont be accessible outside of `function` if you are using `use strict` unless you assign it global scope, in this case you have to either remove `use strict` or prefix your variables with `window.` like so: `window.myVar` .
As `window` is global, your variable will be available outside too.

```js
function myLocalScope() {
  'use strict';

  // Only change code below this line
  window.myVar = "bebe"
  console.log('inside myLocalScope', myVar);
}
myLocalScope();

// Run and check the console
// myVar is not defined outside of myLocalScope
console.log('outside myLocalScope', window.myVar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove "use strict" and it should work . With strict mode, you can not use undeclared variables.

```js
function myLocalScope() {
 
  // Only change code below this line
  myVar = "bebe"
  console.log('inside myLocalScope', myVar);
}
myLocalScope();

// Run and check the console
// myVar is not defined outside of myLocalScope
console.log('outside myLocalScope', myVar);
```